# Adobe Flex DatGrid Sort Descending on Header Click

Tags: flash, apache-flex, sorting, datagrid, default

The default action of a Flex DataGrid header click is to toggle **sort direction** starting with **ascending**.

`<mx:DataGrid dataProvider='{pData}' id="myDataGrid" width="700" height="520" paddingLeft="100" >`

How would I set the sort direction to **descending** on **first click**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [sortDescending](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/dataGridClasses/DataGridColumn.html#sortDescending) property on the DataGridColumn and set it to true.